# A puzzle on game theory

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory

Bob and Alice are playing a game. They will start with an integer $n$. Alice goes first, in each turn, a player can choose an integer between 1 and 13 and that number is to be subtracted from $n$. They will repeat this process alternatively. The game ends when $n$ becomes less than 1. The person who will be the telling the last number will lose the game.

Given $n$ (initial value), how could we determine the value of $n$ after the $k$th turn of Alice (If Alice plays optimally)?

PS: For this particular puzzle, it is given $n = 1251$ and $k = 19$. However, I am interested in the general solution.

Comment: Are $1$ and $13$ allowed integers?

Comment: @Macavity: The puzzle doesn't explicitly say anything about that. But I guess it is inclusive.

Comment: Depends how well Alice plays. It may be a good idea for Alice to lose every so often, in order to keep the sucker hooked. By the way, probably $1$ and $13$ are allowed. Doesn't chane things much either way.

Comment: @Macavity: For this particular puzzle it's given $n = 1251$ and $k = 19$. But I am more interested in finding the general solution.

Comment: Alice wants, on her first move, to make the value $=1 \mod{14}$. Her strategy after this is to subtract $14-b_i$ where $b_i$ is Bob's $i$th move. When Alice eventually ends on exactly $1$, Bob has no choice but to push the value below $1$ and lose.

Comment: Alice's strategy is not given. If $1$ and $13$ are allowed and Alice is able to move to $14r+1$ at any stage, then when Bob plays $b$, Alice can return to a number of the same form by playing $14-b$. Bob's penultimate move is from $15$, from which he cannot win, and Alice plays to $1$, from which Bob must lose. However the question says nothing about the strategy adopted.

Comment: Whoops, got the winning condition backwards, Daniel is exactly right on optimal strategy. (If Alice starts on a number $n\equiv 1\pmod {14}$ then Bob can force a win.

Comment: @MarkBennet If this is a game theory question, you assume that the players are perfectly rational and aim to win.

Comment: And in *most* problems of this sort, "between $1$ and $13$" means that $1,13$ are allowed. Could be different in this case, but we rarely use open intervals when talking about natural numbers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks for spotting that possibility. Alice can only force a win if $n\neq 1\mod 14$.

Comment: @DanielRust. Suppose we start at $29$ and Alice goes first? What is the strategy then - we need it to know what is left after Alice's move.

Comment: @MarkBennet Starting at 29, no strategy is best - she can't win if her opponent plays optimally. I suppose choosing $1$ in this case gives her opponent more time to make a mistake...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Now we have an actual starting position the consideration becomes irrelevant, and there is an actual solution.

Comment: @MarkBennet The OP asked about the general case.

Comment: @DanielRust The general case is that if the starting position is $14r+1$ the problem is indeterminate. We are not told that the opponent plays well, and optimal for Alice is not well-defined.

Comment: @MarkBennet Assuming optimal play is one of the most basic assumptions in game theory. If a player can force a win in a finite game, then the other player's set of optimal strategies is the set of **all** strategies. It is well defined, just not of cardinality one.

Comment: @DanielRust Alice is stated to play optimally, Bob is not. Anyway, if Alice is playing $1$ and Bob has made a suboptimal move, Alice moves to a winning position and the problem is determinate. But there is no unique optimal strategy against a perfect player when you are playing from a lost position - and in this game, against an optimal player, no play delays the ending, so unless more is specified, the value after Alice's $k$th turn is indeterminate, and it is that value which is requested in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Given the strategy outlined in the comments,

- If $n\equiv1\pmod{14}$ then Alice can not win and so her strategy is essentially irrelevant so we can't tell what her $i$th move will be (however we can put bounds on it, given that Bob has a winning strategy).
- If $n\not\equiv 1\pmod{14}$ then Alice's first move will put the counter at $n-(n\bmod 14)+1$. Every subsequent move Alice makes after this will be $14$ less than her $1$st move and so her $i$th move will put the counter at $$n-(n\bmod 14)+1-14(i-1)=n-(n\bmod 14)-14i+15\;.$$

---

Working assumptions:

- *Both players are perfectly rational and aim to win.*
- *Players can choose to reduce the current total by any element in the set $\{1,\ldots, 13\}$.*
- *If a player can not force a win then we can not give an algorithm for their strategy.*
- *Alice adopts the following strategy in the case that $n \not\equiv 1\pmod{14}$. On her first move, she makes the value of the counter $\equiv 1\pmod{14}$. Her strategy after this is to subtract $14−b_i$ where $b_i$ is the element that Bob has chosen to subtract from the counter on his  $i$th move. When Alice eventually ends on exactly $1$, Bob has no choice but to push the value below $1$ and lose.*

Comment: For $\bmod$ as a binary operator use `\bmod`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only integers $\in \{2, 3, ... 12\}$ can be chosen for subtracting, clearly having $n$ of $1$ or $2$ is a bad position.  It follows that $n \in \{3, 4, ...14\}$ is good, as this allows putting your opponent in a bad position at the next turn.  Then $15, 16$ are bad positions, as you end up putting your opponent in a good position.  Then again $\{17, 18, ... 28\}$ are all good.  And so on and so forth...

So if Alice starts with a good $n$, she would subtract the required number to keep Bob bad.  If Alice starts with a bad $n$, tough luck or hope Bob slips.

Comment: Most of the time, when a problem in probability, statistics or game theory says "pick a number from $1$ to $13$" they mean inclusive. Certainly up for interpretation, but that's the most common usage. Would you really expect them to say "between $0$ and $14$?

Comment: @MarkBennet The problem allows negative number results. "The game ends when n becomes less than 1." Says nothing about non-negative.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The OP guessed not inclusive.  Besides this seemed more interesting a case, the other is quite similar and simpler...

Comment: It's true that the OP guessed, but that doesn't mean OP guessed right, and it is usually right to make the guess you'd make. OP is, after all, seeking advice, and OP is *only* guessing - didn't say this interp was sure.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for that accurate reading - apologies for error.